# exported Javascript object vs json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am asking for a suggestion:

I wrote a custom form component in React. The component renders form inputs in a variety of forms (many different forms).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.labelClasses = 'form-label animated-label';
  this.inputClasses = 'form-input animated-input';
  this.buttonClasses = 'vary-button';
  this.userInput = '';

  this.state = {
    touched: false,  
    isActive: false,
    amount: '', // all these will be passed down using props or from redux store
    hasError: false,
    required: true,
    inputType: 'number',
    name: 'Field',
    allowVariation: true,
    step: 10,
    importValue: false
  };
}
```

The differences in these forms is the data that they should receive from the user and how/what the form-component should do with the data.

I can have the data for these form components:
(1) supplied as a JSON file - (and then use fetch/axios to get the data).
(2) I can write actual objects and import (using ES6 imports) it in different forms.

Which approach will be better ?

Comment: Explain what you mean by _import it_. Do. you mean via ES6 import statements or something else?

Comment: Yes, using ES6 imports.

Comment: Either way you have to take steps to download the file into the browser - 1) via XHR AJAX 2) via `<script>` tag. Makes little difference which way you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways work depending on a use case.

If you have a possibility to use local JSON or JS object as a configuration, without security issues, you can use local import without a problem.

If the data you want to import could be changed and should be retrieved on each page reload of your application **or** has some sensitive information, consider storing it at your backend server and retrieve it in any way(axios, AJAX, fetch, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. If you use a JSON file you may be able to change the data easily without much effort.
If you hard code the data as objects, you will have to re-build the project each time you want to change the forms data.

You don't provide much information about the project or how this data is used, so I can't really give you a proper answer, but ask yourself this:
How often the data need to be changed?
Should it even change?. If it shouldn't change, I think hard coding it is just fine.

Again, it all depends on the type of project and what you are exactly trying to achieve. Both options are valid.

Comment: Either way the data is hard coded. If it is a JSON file it is hard coded as JSON. If it is in an ES6 module it is hard coded into an Object.